# Kafka createDirectStream using PySpark with SSL properties

Tags: pyspark, apache-kafka

We have multiple borkers and the connection is being secured with SSL protocol. To create kafka direct stream, I am trying to pass the ssl info as below, but its throwing error,

```
kafkaParams = {"metadata.broker.list": "host1:port,host2:port,host3:port",
"security.protocol":"ssl",
"ssl.key.password":"***",
"ssl.keystore.location":"/path1/file.jks",
"ssl.keystore.password":"***",
"ssl.truststore.location":"/path1/file2.jks",
"ssl.truststore.password":"***"}

directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc,["topic"],kafkaParams)
```

ERROR:

```
>>> directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc,["topic"],kafkaParams)
**20/02/12 11:22:54 WARN utils.VerifiableProperties: Property security.protocol is not valid
20/02/12 11:22:54 WARN utils.VerifiableProperties: Property ssl.key.password is not valid
20/02/12 11:22:54 WARN utils.VerifiableProperties: Property ssl.keystore.location is not valid
20/02/12 11:22:54 WARN utils.VerifiableProperties: Property ssl.keystore.password is not valid
20/02/12 11:22:54 WARN utils.VerifiableProperties: Property ssl.truststore.location is not valid
20/02/12 11:22:54 WARN utils.VerifiableProperties: Property ssl.truststore.password is not valid**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.4.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.13.3.p3544.1321029/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/streaming/kafka.py", line 146, in createDirectStream
    ssc._jssc, kafkaParams, set(topics), jfromOffsets)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.4.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.13.3.p3544.1321029/lib/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.4.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.13.3.p3544.1321029/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.4.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.13.3.p3544.1321029/lib/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o10805.createDirectStreamWithoutMessageHandler.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: java.io.EOFException
java.io.EOFException
java.io.EOFException
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$checkErrors$1.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:387)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$checkErrors$1.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:387)
        at scala.util.Either.fold(Either.scala:98)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$.checkErrors(KafkaCluster.scala:386)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.getFromOffsets(KafkaUtils.scala:223)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtilsPythonHelper.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:721)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtilsPythonHelper.createDirectStreamWithoutMessageHandler(KafkaUtils.scala:689)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**onthe otherhand tried readStream by passing the SSL information as below, and that works without any issue, so not sure how to pass the SSL information as the main objective is to have DStream**

```
kafkaParams = "host1:port,host2:port,host3:port'"
topic = "topic"

df= spark.readStream.format("kafka")\
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers",kafkaParams)\
.option("kafka.security.protocol", "SSL")\
.option("kafka.ssl.truststore.location", SparkFiles.get("file.jks")) \
.option("kafka.ssl.truststore.password", "***") \
.option("kafka.ssl.keystore.location", SparkFiles.get("file1.jks")) \
.option("kafka.ssl.keystore.password", "***") \
.option("subscribe",topic)\
.option("startingOffsets","earliest")\
.load()

df1 = df.selectExpr("CAST(value as STRING)","timestamp")
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StringType

df_schema = StructType()\
.add("cust_id",StringType())\
.add("name",StringType())\
.add("age",StringType())\
.add("address",StringType())

from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json,col

df2 = df1.select(from_json(col("value"),df_schema).alias("df_a"),"timestamp")

df_console_write = df2\
.writeStream\
.trigger(processingTime='10 seconds')\
.option("truncate","false")\
.format("console")\
.start()

df_console_write.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: do you have answer for this ? I am having the same issue.